# Does Google Cloud Test Lab support Appium tests?

Tags: android, testng, appium, google-cloud-test-lab

We are using **Appium** with testNG to test our android app. As I was researching about the cloud test labs, I didn't find any documentation regarding **Google Cloud Test Lab** supporting appium tests.

1. So, does google test cloud support Appium tests?
2. Further more research lead me to Amazon web services, Sauce labs and Xamarin test cloud. Which of these is best for android app testing?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 7):

Today Google Cloud Test Lab (now Firebase Test Lab) does not support running Appium Tests.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Amazon web services support Appium Tests. Have you used it?

Comment: No, but then I work for Google and manage the Test Lab team. :)

Comment: Firebase Test Lab can be used for iOS Application ?

Comment: @JustinBroughton Is it in the roadmap to support Appium? Thanks!

Comment: @JustinBroughton Any news on this?